# Can Jinns (shaytan, iblees) read your thoughts and feelings?

Tags: shaitan, jinn, evil-eye, evil-thoughts

I feel that my question has been answered lighly [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7465/does-the-shaytaan-know-the-thoughts-and-intentions-of-man-to-corrupt-it). The answer to this question would lead to sub questions that changes due to the answer of this question.

First, **can Jinns/Shayatin/Iblees read our thoughts?**

If that is true, wouldn't this be a contradiction? Because the quran clearly states:

> 27:65: Say: None in the heavens or on earth, except Allah, knows what is
>   hidden: nor can they perceive when they shall be raised up (for
>   Judgment).

Sub question: **If Jinns cannot read our thoughts, how can he waswas (whisper negatively) to us when we think about a certain subject?** You could say, he is the one, that in the first place whispered to you to think about that subject. But that wouldn't be logically valid in all scenarios. There are scenarios where the jinn couldn't be the one that started the subject (which then lead to negatively thoughts), that some might call waswas from the shaytan. In that case how could the shaytan waswas to you about that subject without knowing what you think? Maybe our definition of waswas and of shaytan in the context of waswas is wrong?

Sub question: **If Jinns cannot read our thoughts, how can he know that we are jelaous on someone?** Scholars had said that jinns fuel are jealousy, which lead the jinns to do something evil on the person you are casting the evil eye on. [Sources (Youtube 3:45)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mzk4vi-tNA)

If they cannot read our thoughts and knowing that we are getting jelaous at someone, they wouldn't be able to feed on that jelaousy and by that doing something evil on the person. The evil eye, just by thought would in that way not be able to be caused by a jinn. Who is it caused by then?

*My questions are marked bold, everything else are comments around them.*

The hadiths and verses in the Quran doesn't clearly state thus anywhere. Indeed the Hadith and verses clearly says that Satan only whispers onto human.

Answer (score 1):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

*I will try to answer as per my knowledge, if anything in my answer is wrong, let me know i will update the answer.* Being said that, let's move to the answer.

Let's first quote a hadees,

> Anas ibn Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings
>   be upon him, was in the company of one of his wives when a man passed
>   by them. The Prophet called to him and when he came, the Prophet said,
>   “She is my wife.” The man said, “O Messenger of Allah, I do not doubt
>   you in the least.” The Prophet said, **“Verily, Satan flows through the
>   human being like blood.”**
>
> [Sahih Muslim 2174](https://sunnah.com/muslim/39/32)

Now, this hadees has 2 important points in it, first is that shayateen flows in our body, and when something is in our body like blood, it will obviously know everything about our body. But keep in mind, not all shayateen runs in our body, as described in another hadees.

> It was narrated that ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Mas’ood said: The Messenger of
>   Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: **“There is no
>   one among you but a companion from among the jinn has been assigned to
>   him.” They said, “Even you, O Messenger of Allaah?’ He said, “Even me,
>   but Allaah helped me with him and he became Muslim (or: and I am safe
>   from him), so he only enjoins me to do that which is good.”**
>
> According to another report, “… There is assigned to him a companion
>   from among the jinn and a companion from among the angels.”
>
> [Narrated by Muslim, 2814](https://sunnah.com/muslim/52/62)

This companion(the devil one), which is commonly referred to as "[Qareen](https://islamqa.info/en/26226)"(arabic word meaning companion) is devil and it is directly responsible for all the wasawas and bad things in your mind, like Allah says in quran:

> “**His companion (qareen) will say**: ‘Our Lord! I did not push him to
>   transgression, (in disbelief, oppression, and evil deeds), but he was
>   himself in error far astray.’
>
> Allaah will say: ‘Dispute not in front of Me, I had already in advance
>   sent you the threat.
>
> The Sentence that comes from Me cannot be changed, and I am not unjust
>   to the slaves’”
>
> [Qaaf 50:27-29]

and

> ‘And Shaytaan (Satan) will say when the matter has been decided:
>   “Verily, Allaah promised you a promise of truth. **And I too promised
>   you, but I betrayed you. I had no authority over you except that I
>   called you, and you responded to me. So blame me not, but blame
>   yourselves.** I cannot help you, nor can you help me. I deny your former
>   act in associating me (Satan) as a partner with Allaah (by obeying me
>   in the life of the world). Verily, there is a painful torment for the
>   Zaalimoon (polytheists and wrongdoers).”’
>
> [Ibraaheem 14:22]

And there are other verses like these in quran. The point i want to make is, that their is a devil associated with each person and it runs like blood in veins. Now, this does not mean we are alone in fighting it, as mentioned in above hadees, their is also an angel who is there to protect us. Now if we do things which make angel feel bad, it will move a little away from you, because those things kind of torture him, and shatan will be closer and happy. And if you do good things, which are a torture to shatan, shatan will feel pain and will be a little away, and angel will be happy and will be more close to you. This explanation is what i have heard from some big scholars and this totally makes sense after all above ahadees and ayahs.

Now, the **second thing which the first hadees tells us** is that prophet told the man that she is my wife, and he said i don't doubt you, but prophet saying "Satan flows through the human being like blood" means that it is satan who whispers and put bad thoughts in the mind of people. And prophet feared that satan might had whispered in his ear too, that's why he explained.

**Now, we know that satan runs like blood in veins, and it can whisper in our mind, and it running like blood implies he would know anything in the mind or heart of the man too...**

Now, **this is not in contradiction with the verse you quoted. Because, firstly, jinns don't know the future, and every jinn don't know about the heart of every person, he knows about the person he is attached to only**. So, hidden is still hidden and he knows what Allah has enabled him to know. There is no contradiction, we must understand that the **definition of hidden is not same for everyone,** for example if I don't know what's inside some room, it's possible some other person who has seen inside of the room knows what's inside, so we can't say he knows all the hidden things, but yes, he know something which is hidden for us.

All your sub-questions were on supposition that jins cannot read our thoughts, but as i explained, they do. So, i suppose their is nothing to clear in them.

One more thing i should mention is, that the  people who are attached to spiritual healing and stuff like that like the persons who are possessed by jinns or devils, they know that the jinn inside the body knows everything a man is thinking or seeing or feeling, but the external jinns don't know it, and sometimes internal jinns communicate with external ones to let them know about the person. But external ones don't know anything like that themselves, they are just told sometimes.

Read [sources of whispers/wasawas.](https://islamqa.info/en/39684)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time. May Allah reward you. I perfectly agree with this: "Now, the second thing which the first hadees tells us is that prophet told the man that she is my wife, and he said i don't doubt you, but prophet saying "Satan flows through the human being like blood" means that it is satan who whispers and put bad thoughts in the mind of people. And prophet feared that satan might had whispered in his ear too, that's why he explained." --- But I do not see how we can draw in conclusion by this and the other references that therefore they can read our minds.

Comment: Reading the hadith (“Verily, Satan flows through the human being like blood.”) in it's context, in Arabic, we cannot draw a conclusion and say that this means that Satan can read our thoughts. See for instance this: http://sunnah.com/bukhari/33/10 "فَقَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ إِنَّ الشَّيْطَانَ يَبْلُغُ مِنَ الإِنْسَانِ مَبْلَغَ الدَّمِ، وَإِنِّي خَشِيتُ أَنْ يَقْذِفَ فِي قُلُوبِكُمَا شَيْئًا ‏", "I was afraid lest Satan might insert an evil thought in your minds."... i.e after they saw him then Satan made them think of an evil thought.

Comment: If a shatan who does not know your thoughts, how can he inject something in your thoughts, i mean for example, i am thinking about Allah and his creations, suddenly a waswasa comes to the mind about Allah himself. Now its not like i am thinking about my career or something and a waswasa comes about Allah. Though it is possible but it seems logical that to inject some bad thought, one must have access to your thoughts.

Comment: I don't claim that this hadees implies or any other hadees explicitly says that shayateen or jinn know our thoughts, but it is probable that something which is in our body like our blood, and it has power to inject wasawas it has to know the thoughts. Also, as i wrote in the answer, all the people who have experience with treatment of possessed people and stuff like that, they know and they tell that when some jinn is IN the body of a person, he knows everything a man is thinking. And sometimes it tells those things. Keep in mind i wrote in answer that only internal jinn can know the thoughts.

Comment: lastly i should also say, that jinns are week and human are more powerful, and with the help of Allah's book it becomes more stronger. And verily, the resistance for jinns, internal or external, for reading our thoughts, or injecting wasawas increases. And its not the case like its easy or they are always reading our thoughts, it is just that they can.

Comment: That is exactly what i was asking in my sub question, read it again: "If Jinns cannot read our thoughts, how can he waswas (whisper negatively) to us when we think about a certain subject?"

Comment: Well, i am not saying they can't, what i am saying is only internal jinns can, but there is nothing DECLARING this in quran or hadees, it is more of the experience thing which we have learnt and concluded.

Answer (score -1):

> Say: No one in the heavens and the earth knows the unseen but Allah;
>   and they do not know when they shall be raised. [27:56][[Shakir
>   Translation]](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=27&verse=65)

The word “hidden” in your quoted translation has multiple connotations. To my limited knowledge, it is not hidden in the sense of “being out of sight or not readily apparent,” but rather (or most of the time) “the unknown future.”

To my limited knowledge, there is one point that we are absolutely certain about, the knowledge (the time) of the Judgment Day exclusively belongs to Allah. Nobody, not even the prophets, not even the Angel Gabriel, has any idea about that knowledge:

> He (Gabriel) inquired: "Tell me about the Hour (the Day of
>   Resurrection)." He (Prophet Muhammad)  replied, "I have no more
>   knowledge thereof than you". [Riyad as-Salihin](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/60)

(In general, the knowledge of future is exclusive to Allah only.)

As mentioned by Zia Ul Rehman Mughal in his answer, everybody is assigned with a devil who stays with him 24/7. Watching and observing you continuously, he knows you better than you know yourself. He knows what your desires are, what your vulnerabilities are, and gives you "waswasa" accordingly.

What I still do not know is that whether there is an unambiguously clear hadith that mentions whether the same devil, or Satan for that matter, can actually read our thoughts? For example, say something happens and I think of myself "You stupid devil, you cannot fool me!" Does that devil aware of this thought? (I think he does, because he gives me further waswasa.)

Also:

> And certainly did Our messengers come to Abraham with good tidings;
>   they said, "Peace." He said, "Peace," and did not delay in bringing
>   [them] a roasted calf. But when he saw their hands not reaching for
>   it, he distrusted them and felt from them apprehension. They said,
>   "Fear not. We have been sent to the people of Lot." [11:69-70] [Sahih
>   International](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=11&verse=69)

Apparently, those visiting angels (Gabriel being one of them) could see Prophet Abraham's heart and that fear entered his heart when they did not touch the food.

Comment: Downvoter please explain your action.

Answer (score -2):

I will give you a short an concise answer, without beating around the bush. Yes they can. I am not a sheik or a scholar but I have a lot of experience in this topic. I have done telepathy using black magic to talk to people individually and large groups of people (sometimes over hundreds of people) for over 2 years. And people have talked back using jinns. Not only can Jinn listen into your thoughts but they can sense our feelings and what we visually imagine, and they can transmit this to other people. They can also probe into your memory, about thing we have done in the past. I have also made people see things (dragons, snakes, even transform a whole hall way into a moor with cows) just by thinking of it. Sometimes I would make people naked infrount of everyone, or make them go up in flames, just by imaging that it was happening to them infrount of me. I have also given people the sensation of being shocked by electricity, by thinking it. Jinns can also block your thoughts, you might be engaged in a conversation and the jinn will block your thought so you will not be able to continue the conversation. They can also block your faith completely and other feelings or convictions you may have. And Jinns can do alot more than this but I have only said the things relating to reading your thoughts, feeling and what you imagine to answer the question you have posted.

You might think that I am some kind of evil magician by this. I am no magician, but this magic was done on me by people who wanted to know what I was thinking.

Answer (score -3):

Pbuh was blackmagiced by Jew,so he had an oblivion on having relationship with his wife then inspiration came of surah falaq ,he recited the surah again and again then the shayataan which put evil thoughts accepted and embrace d Islam ao that he can command to do right things only ....

I see many people in my lifetime that they know what we are thinking about...their supposition are mostly right and they guess what we exactly thinking.. and some can tremble upon you....you experience on many occasions ....but actually you fear them not ...this all sort of things ... Because there are two things conscious and subconscious
Conscious mind can response ,in state of subconscious the one inside you come if you mess if took seriously for the revenge Only the experience on this particular can read what person thought would be because to him personally is more important than the lie expose by their minds .... because no one knows when the state of person change .... There is shaiytaan associated with every person whoever do evil will face consequence and there will no life for them or they have stay in hell forsoever .who repent for their actions will get Allah mercy . To my knowledge that some people can control by evil things ,fire is the resting place for them ,,,, because shaiytaan is the one who help them and theirs masters they know what their are doing and in end shaiytaan overcome them and let them in astray them and their offspring this is a greatest victory for shaitaan,so he offer anything and everything and beautify their hearts soul and eyes with earthly life with wealth heap of gold women's etc...

So anything that you had confusion with it compare to the Quran and hadees that is appropriate to do or not ,if not leave and seek protection from evil of Allah..

Because Quran was revealed for the life of earth and hereafter...

Surely there is a guidance for may complicated distressful life and illumine your soul ....

The more you have problems mean the more person loved by him ..

Some take shaiytaan as their companion so he led them only in error but they can not understand or preceive it..

There is also another Hadith where pbuh says the day will come where nothing is hidden to the public everything has no screen  between him and public..

There many duas (aadkar )for us if we start bring in our life that could be solution for all ...

Anything you do surity and trust has must  and pure heart.

And Allah says in Quran don't  has close relationship with disbeliever because that might cause you to fall in error because of the love and affection can cause you to be transgress what Allah ordained,,,,so actually they are not so shaiytaan comes any possible way he can to delude the person..

And people of same liking will join together..

We live our life for Allah swh and he showed us way to live which is better for you in earth and hereafter..
Nothing in the heaven and Earth escape from his knowledge.
And jinn cannot here what happen in the heaven whenever try to eavesdrop a burning fire catch them .. but in Quran in place allah say about life of the heaven and hell and explain all of the creation and scriptures and prophets everything about .

Jinn are only there to cause mischeif and lead humans to follow their footsteps and let them to stay in error,it can deceive any brain because it is one which bring thought to do and it is so adamant in nature and it pursue any one which bring harm to them so they start to frighten them as revenge ,we can't win them by brain we can protection from them  from way prophet Allah showed.

If Allah strengthen our heart and bearness we can get protection from their harm  ,

When you do mischeif which harm others they you are on closely associated with shaitaan and his companion so that only cause to be in negative thoughts only.

May Allah Grant us the highest rewards and enjoins with those bestows and make our life pleasant and victory over all the evils.